# <s : if test > tag in jsp file not working

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tags, struts

I want to compare the value of a label from `.properties` in .jsp file. The value of label is fetched from `.properties` file.

The syntax i used was `<s:if test="%{label.language eq 'true'}">`

where `label.language` is a label defined in `.properties' file.

The label is defined in properties file as `label.language=true`.

But the control never jumps inside the `if` block.

Please help!

Comment: Try  <s:if test="%{getText('label.language') == 'true'}">

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot..!